# Sum with orthogonal complement always closed only in Hilbert spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Is the following statement true?
If $V$ is an inner product space over $\mathbb{K} \in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$ such that $U + U^{\perp}$ is a closed subspace of $V$ for every closed subspace $U \subseteq V$, then $V$ is a Hilbert space.

Comment: I have found a proof, the statement is true. So the following are equivalent for an inner product space $V$: 1) $V$ is a Hilbert space, 2) $U_1+U_2$ is closed for all closed subspaces $U_1, U_2 \subseteq V$ such that $U_1 \perp U_2$, 3) $U+U^{\perp}$ is closed for every closed subspace $U \subseteq V$.